# How to read the value in a BINARY column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a `BINARY(35)` column to a table in which values are written whose bits are each assigned to a specific meaning.

i.e. "000110001010..."

1st bit: day 1,
2nd bit: day 2, 
etc..

I've found out how to write the value into the table

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(x'03011...');
```

but how do I retrieve it from the database?

If I cast the column as a character string, I'll loose everything past the first `x'00' (NULL)` in the value.  In my application, its entirely possible that they'll still be '1's past this.

Because I'm using the C++ connector, I've only its API functions to retrieve the data so I'll need to know the type of the data retrieved. The API does not have a `getBinary()` function. If any of you can tell me which function to use, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE`

Comment: If you're avoiding columns to begin with for some weird reason, why do you bother with binary? Stick a number in if you're so bent for saving space and making things harder for yourself. Your "binary" corresponds to a number. Also, this is the wrong way to use the databases, you could have gone with a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from another Q&A site.

SELECT HEX(mycolumn) FROM MYTABLE;

If anyone wants to read more about this:
Hexidecimal Literals: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

Bit-Field Literals: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

Substring(cast column as varchar), 1,1)